# Acrobat Forms - Connecting Fields

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Goal: JavaScript code to link fields to auto fill once top field is full. Lines will range from 2 to 5 (have multiple areas with different total number of lines in each.)

Want to be able to have lines visible. Acrobat's current option for multiple lines auto sizes text and line spacing to fit, so visible lines don't work. User currently has to recognize that field is filling (type is auto sizing to fit) then physically move cursor down to next line.

Example (link below): Comments: Would like this area to auto fill across top line then automatically jump to next line to continue comments.

I work with Acrobat a lot but have very little knowledge of writing JavaScript code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The form will only be filled with Keystroke (no scripts or prefill options will be available.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Do not care about the writing lines, and use the font size/line
   spacing provided by the multiline field.
2. Use the richText feature of the field.
3. Work with individual connected fields on the writing lines.

To 3: (I go backwards with these comments): Looking like the simplest solution. However, the crucial property is only available in the Keystroke event, which means it does not work when you fill the fields via script or prefill.

To 2: You can preset the properties of the field for manual filling. For filling via script, you would have to create a richText Object. This is not thaaat difficult, but can be a bit complicated.

To 1: This is the easiest way, and, because filling out on screen or via script does not need writing lines; so, you can make the background of the multiline field white and cover the writing lines.

If ever possible, I would go for option 1.

Comment: @ MaxWyss
@ Max Wyss
3) The form will only be filled with Keystroke (no scripts or prefill options will be available.)

2) As I understand it Rich Text only allows control of text, at least the rich text controls available in Acrobat...if you have another solution on how to add, please post directions.

1) So it's NOT an option not to have the lines.